# Login view control with coustom log in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net webpage that contain a custom login control like this:

```
                    <div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    User Name:</div>
                <div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" CssClass="form-login"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div id="login-box-name">
                    Password:</div>
                <div id="login-box-field">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" CssClass="form-login" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <br />
                <span class="login-box-options">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1">
                    Remember Me</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="loginbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/login-btn.png" 
                    onclick="loginbtn_Click" />
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

and on the "loginbtn_Click" :

```
if(Membership.ValidateUser(username.Text,password.Text))
   {
       var user = Membership.GetUser(username.Text);
       var userid = user.ProviderUserKey;
       Session["UserID"] = userid;
       Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
   }
```

and the 'login view control' is like this:

```
<li>
                        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                            <RoleGroups>
                                <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admins">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <a href="ControlPanel.aspx">Control Panel</a>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:RoleGroup>
                                <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Users">
                                </asp:RoleGroup>
                            </RoleGroups>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </li>
```

but my problem is after the admin logs in the 'login view' control doesn't show the link named 'control panel' , is it because the custom control i made for the log in or i missed the e.Authenticated = true;..or something else??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Authorization cookie

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username.Text, true);
```

Also on logout make sure you clear it:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```